# Distribution symmetry proof

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have three *dependent* random variables $X,Y,Z$ and a well-behaved function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that the random vector $(X,Y)$ has the same distribution as the random vector $(Y,X)$, meaning that $P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)=P(Y\leq x,X\leq y)$, for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

How can I prove that the random vectors $(g(X,Z),g(Y,Z))$ and $(g(Y,Z),g(X,Z))$ have the same distribution?

That is, I want to prove that $P(g(X,Z)\leq t,g(Y,Z)\leq u)=P(g(Y,Z)\leq t,g(X,Z)\leq u)$ for every $t,u\in\mathbb{R}$. This result seems kind of intuitive to me, and I thought about conditioning on $Z$, but can't figure out the complete argument.

Comment: Welcome to the site ! If you have a follow up question it is best that you make a new post. On stackexchange we try to have one question per post.

Comment: Sorry! I removed the follow-up and posted a new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617933/distribution-symmetry-given-some-information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange!

It seems that we need $Z$ to be independent of $(X,Y)$ if we want the result to hold. Otherwise, we get a counter-example by letting $g(u,v)=u-v$, $Z=X$ and $Y$ such that $Y-X$ is not constant equal to $0$ but having the same law as $X$.

When $Z$ is independent of $(X,Y)$, define $h_z(u)=g(u,z)$. Then for each Borel subsets $A$ and $B$ of the real line,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(g(X,Z)\in A,g(Y,Z)\in B)&=\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb P(g(X,z)\in A,g(Y,z)\in B)d\mathbb P_Z(z)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb P( X \in h_z^{-1}(A),Y\in h_z^{-1}(B))d\mathbb P_Z(z)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb P( Y \in h_z^{-1}(A),X\in h_z^{-1}(B))d\mathbb P_Z(z)\\
&=\mathbb P(g(X,Z)\in B,g(Y,Z)\in A).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much, Davide! I edited the question and posted a follow-up. Would you please take a look? Thanks again.

Comment: I will have a look at your new question, which is also interesting. Usually on this website, a common practice is to post followup-up questions as a new question.